# Windows 10 - Click a window without pulling it in front

Tags: windows-10

Hello friends I was just wondering if there is an option in Windows 10, where I can click on window, which is in layout deeper than the others without pulling it in front.

Example: I have large display, I have many small windows oppened (git bashes for example) and I can see youtube video in the background (I can see just a part of it, but I have enough space to click). When I click on browser, it gets to the front and all my bashes are behind it.

I just want to click on browser to pause video, WITHOUT dragging browser window to the top. Is there a way?

PS: I am asking here, I tried to google it but I have no idea how to choose my keywords.

Thanks in advance.